# My CodeEditor Android app becomes slow because the algorithm check for words to highlight every time a letter is written. How can i fix it?

Tags: android, algorithm, editor, syntax-highlighting

After a few minutes of writing it becomes really slow because the algorithm keeps controlling the whole written text looking for words to highlight. The problem is that it checks the text every time a letter is written.

How can I change this algorithm to make the app faster and usable?

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String input = s.toString();
                String[] words = input.split(SPACE);
 int start = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<words.length ;i++){
                    String word = words[i];

                    if(map.containsKey(word)){

                        int index = input.indexOf(word, start);
                        String color = map.get(word);
                        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), index, index+word.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        start = index+word.length();
                    }
                }
```

Here is the whole ActivityMain of the app.

```
package com.example.android.editor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.example.android.editor.R.id.editText;


/**
 *  ------------
 *   30/03/2017
 *  ------------
 * */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    String projectTitle;






    //send code via social Networks

    public void invia(View view) {
        String shareBody = "File: " + editTextTitle.getText().toString() + "\n\n" +editTextBody.getText().toString();
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
    }




    public void save(View view) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        String content = editTextBody.getText().toString();
        pref.setPrefs(pref.sharedPrefsProjects);


        startActivity(new Intent(this, SelectProject.class));


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(projectTitle)) {

                pref.removeValue(content);
                pref.saveStringValue(title, content);

                if(!projectTitle.equals(title)) {
                    pref.removeValue(projectTitle);
                    pref.removeValue(content);//adri
                    pref.saveStringValue(title, content);
                }
            } else {
                pref.removeValue(content);//adri
                pref.saveStringValue(title, content);
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(this, SelectProject.class));
        }

    }



    //This function make possible to insert tab
    public void tab(View view) {

        editTextBody.getText().insert(editTextBody.getSelectionStart(), "\t\t\t\t");
    }



    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    EditText editTextTitle, editTextBody;
    SharedPref pref;

    private final static String SPACE = "\\s";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titolo);
        editTextBody = (EditText)findViewById(editText);

        pref = new SharedPref(this);
        //dictionary of words to be highlighted and colors
        map.put("if", "#00E676");
        map.put("else", "#00E676");
        map.put("for", "#00E676");
        map.put("while", "#00E676");
        map.put("do", "#00E676");

        map.put("int", "#e91e63");
        map.put("void", "#e91e63");
        map.put("sizeof", "#e91e63");
        map.put("char", "#e91e63");
        map.put("bool", "#e91e63");
        map.put("float", "#e91e63");
        map.put("double", "#e91e63");
        map.put("unsigned", "#e91e63");
        map.put("+", "#e91e63");
        map.put("-", "#e91e63");
        map.put("=", "#e91e63");

        map.put("false", "#2196F3");
        map.put("true", "#2196F3");
        map.put("main", "#2196F3");
        map.put("<stdio.h", "#2196F3");
        map.put("<stdlib.h", "#2196F3");
        map.put("printf", "#2196F3");
        map.put("scanf", "#2196F3");
        map.put("alloc", "#2196F3");
        map.put("malloc", "#2196F3");
        map.put("realloc", "#2196F3");

        map.put("%c", "#673AB7");
        map.put("%d", "#673AB7");
        map.put("%f", "#673AB7");

        map.put("(", "#FFEB3B");
        map.put(")", "#FFEB3B");
        map.put("(){", "#FFEB3B");
        map.put("()", "#FFEB3B");
        map.put("{", "#FFEB3B");
        map.put("}", "#FFEB3B");

        map.put("1", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("2", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("3", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("4", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("5", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("6", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("7", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("8", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("9", "#7C4DFF");
        map.put("0", "#7C4DFF");

        map.put("*", "#FFFFFF");



        editTextBody.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }




            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String input = s.toString();
                String[] words = input.split(SPACE);




   //FUNCTION THAT HIGHLIGHT WORDS
   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM 


                int start = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<words.length ;i++){
                    String word = words[i];

                    if(map.containsKey(word)){

                        int index = input.indexOf(word, start);
                        String color = map.get(word);
                        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), index, index+word.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        start = index+word.length();
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        if(getIntent() != null) {
            projectTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
            String projectBody = getIntent().getStringExtra("body");




            editTextBody.setText(projectBody);
            editTextTitle.setText(projectTitle);

        }


    }
}
```

If you could write down some code it would be a great help.

Comment: Rather than updating the formatting after every character, update the formatting after a pause in typing. Your `afterTextChanged()` is merely starting or resetting a timer (e.g., `postDelayed()` on the `TextView`), where you update the formatting when the timer goes off. I have seen 500ms used as a common "OK, the user stopped typing briefly" delay period. If you switch to using RxJava/RxAndroid, "debounce" can handle this for you IIRC.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I'll try your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array to store and re-scan all word just check for LAST word

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String input = s.toString();
            String word = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("\s"));

                int index = input.lastIndexOf("\s");

                if(map.containsKey(word)){
                    String color = map.get(word);
                    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), index, 
                    index+word.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            }
```

This should get the work done.

Comment: I implemented that code, it seems to be right but it doesn't work. Maybe it's me, if you send me the whole main activity with that implemented I can try to run it again